# Expect scripting: remote database backup automation

Tags: mysql, expect

I'm looking for a kind of remote database backup automation.
Then, I came across a scripting language which commonly used for administrative tasks, "Expect scripting" and I believe it could serve my purpose very well.

what I'd like to do is I want to perform login to a remote server using the following bash script from my local linux box. (supposed everything has been set properly, SSH authentication via generated key pair, so no password is required)
For the most important part, I'd like to send a mysqldump command to perform backup for my database on that server.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set login "root"
set addr "192.168.1.1"

spawn ssh $login@$addr
expect "#"
send "cd /tmp\r"
expect "#"
send "mysqldump -u root -ppassword my_database > my_database.sql\r"
expect "#"
send "exit\r"
```

The only problem I found here was after the line send "mysqldump -u root....... ".
It was never waiting until the process to finish, but immediately exit the shell with 'send "exit\r"' command line.

what do I do to make it waits until mysqldump command finish and log off the SSH properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your question: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the program to see what's going on.

However, since you have ssh keys set up, you don't really need expect at all:

```
ssh $login@$addr 'cd /tmp && mysqldump -u root -ppassword my_database > my_database.sql'
```